# Review the code to copy List of custom class to another list of Custom class

Tags: java

Thanks for the Reply.

Here is the actual Scenario 
My application received the data from a backend in the form of a class object ie.

```
public class FlowObject { 
private String id; 
private List<FlowStep> flowlSteps; 
private List<String> audRefs; 

}
```

Now FlowStep class as mentioned above is

```
public class FlowStep { 

private String id; 
public String getId() { 
return id; 
} 
public void setId(String id) { 
this.id = id; 
} 

}
```

---

Now since Backend code is NOT ready Im writing the dummy implementation of backend FlowObject Class at my Side whose data gets copied to my local Class FlowCopy 
Thats why I need to write both FlowObject and FlowCopy Classes

Now My Backend Dummpy Implemetation of FlowObject is as below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.List;  
public class FlowObject {  
    private String id;  
    private List<FlowStep> flowlSteps;  
    private List<String> audRefs;  
    public String getId() {  
            return id;  
        }  
        public void setId(String id) {  
            this.id = id;  
        }  
        public List<FlowStep> getFlowSteps() {  
            return flowlSteps;  
        }  
        public void setFlowSteps(List<FlowStep> flowlSteps) {  
            this.flowlSteps= flowlSteps;  
        }  
        public List<String> getAudRefs() {  
            return audRefs;  
        }  
        public void setAudRefs(List<String> audRefs) {  
            this.audRefs = audRefs;  
        }  
}
```

And public class FlowStep {

```
private String id;  

 public String getId() {  
    return id;  
}  
public void setId(String id) {  
    this.id = id;  
}
```

}

and my local FlowCopy Class is as below

```
public class FlowCopy {  
    private String id;  
    private List<FlowStep> flowSteps;  
    private List<String> audRefs;  

    public String getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setId(String id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  
    public List<FlowStep> getFlowSteps() {  
        return flowSteps;  
    }  
    public void setFlowlSteps(List<FlowStep> flowSteps) {  
        this.flowSteps= flowSteps;  
    }  
    public List<String> getAudRefs() {  
        return audRefs;  
    }  
    public void setAudRefs(List<String> audRefs) {  
        this.audRefs = audRefs;  
    }  
}
```

Now my intention is to Copy the Custom FlowObject Class to a list of FlowCopy which will be used in application

```
public List<FlowCopy> getFlow(  List<FlowObject > obj  ){  
       List<FlowCopy> flowRes = new ArrayList<FlowCopy>(obj.size());  
       for (FlowObject object:obj)  
       {  
           FlowCopy  callFlow = new FlowCopy();  
           callFlow.setId(object.getId());  
           callFlow.setAudioRefs(object.getAudRefs());  
           callFlow.setCallSteps(object.getFlowSteps());  
           flowRes .add(callFlow);  

       }  
     return flowRes ;  
   }
```

Please review the above implemetation and suggest a suitable approach

Comment: The first problem I see is that your FlowStep is mutable; as such, if an element of a list in FlowObject is still referenced by another method and it modifies it, the list in FlowObject sees that change. Is that intended? Also, you set and get Lists directly; same problem: collections are mutable

Comment: Thanks , So what changes u suggest ? Please let me know

Comment: I can't really know unless I know the use case; for instance, are there potentially several threads accessing a same FlowObject? Are there potentially threads putting a FlowStep in a List but keeping a reference to it? I can only list the possibilities in an answer if you like, but proposing code to fit your model requires knowing the model ;)

Comment: Copying objects is tedious, you could consider Dozer which does deep object copies with no configuration if the property names match: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

One thing I guess you can consider is to add a constructor for class FlowCopy that handles (or encapsulates) the copy task to release this burden from function getFlow():

```
public class FlowCopy {
    public FlowCopy(FlowObject obj) {
        setId(obj.getId());  
        setAudioRefs(obj.getAudRefs());  
        setCallSteps(obj.getFlowSteps());
    }
   ...
}
```